# How to check in android how a program crashed?

Tags: android, runnable, crash

Is there a tooling or maybe a log, where I can see what caused my application running on a android mobile phone, to hung or eventually crash?

I have programmed a signed application that is a runnable, it checks for messages on my server and send sms messages to a receiver, and after two or maybe 3 days, the application hungs or crashes.

How can I see what caused the crash?

Regards.

Shafqat

```
    private void startservice() {
    r = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            //execute the sms class and get the url
            //build the url
            SendSMS sms = null;
            //TODO get the url from a database
            Map<String, String> jsonitems = new JSONParser().parse(urlsmsservice+getDeviceId());
            if(!jsonitems.isEmpty()){
                sms = new SendSMS(context, jsonitems.get("PHONENUMBER").toString(), jsonitems.get("MESSAGE").toString());
                sentReceiver.setCallbackUrl(jsonitems.get("CALLBACKURL").toString());
                deliveredReceiver.setCallbackUrl(jsonitems.get("CALLBACKURL").toString());
                sms.send();
            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "No messages in Queue");
            }
            //handler.postDelayed(this, getInterval());
        }
    };

    handler = new Handler();
    thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(thbool) {
                    sleep(getInterval());
                    handler.post(r);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure ADB tools are installed (they will be with the SDK). Then run `adb logcat`, which will show the system log output (useful is an exception is thrown). There are also free market applications which will show you the logcat buffer (`aLogCat` comes to mind).

Comment: +1 to Yann. Check out the great DOCUMENTATION that Android has, ADB and logcat are some of the first things you should get familiar with. Also, apps like "Quick System Info" and others can show you the logs, and, if your app is on the Market, the info screen on the publish site (that only you can see) has error/crash details too.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information, I will install this on the device and will let you all know if it has helped me.

Comment: I have installed aLogCat, I have also inspected the log, but I don't see if any exception is thrown in my app, or android itself